# Draggable div Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to be able to drag the main wrapper by pushing the header div.

The main wrapper div that i want to drag is #popupContact

The header div is called #popupHeaderGradient.

Now im using Jquery UI and I got it to work with $('#popupHeaderGradient').draggable();

But this only allows me to move the header element.

I want it to drag the whole main wrapper by dragging on the header element.

Comment: ubercooluk: Thats what i need. $('#popupHeaderGradient').draggable(); is working as i wrote but im trying to get headergradient to drag the whole main wrapper

Comment: If the question is explanatory, I guess there is no need of code.

Comment: what are you dragging and what is moving is virtual here? if you have code here we can see how it is implemented and can solve the issues

Comment: No need, the two answers below works just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#popupContact').draggable({handle: "#popupHeaderGradient"});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the handle option to tell jquery what you want to use as the "drag handle"

```
$('#popupContact').draggable({
   handle: '#popupHeaderGradient'
});
```